# Clone or copy of existing Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

How to copy existing Crystal Reports to the project? This should not affect the changes to the original Crystal Reports.

I have a Crystal Reports at : `E:\DM Accounting Packages\Invoice.rpt`. And I want to make use of `Invoice.rpt` into same project with another name e.g. `GR.rpt` which should not affect original copy of `Invoice.rpt`. How to I make use of existing crystal reports and save it with new copy without affect original?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the original invoice.rpt to another report as a subreport or simply trying to duplicate the report in the same folder in your project?

Comment: @noa, Yes I am using Visual Studio

Comment: I want duplicate the report in the same folder where origninal report exists.

Answer (score 19):

Very Simple !!

Add a New Crystal Report from Visual Studio Project.

[image: Adding a Crystal Report]

After adding a New Crystal Report, you can see a Dialog Box 'Crystal Report Gallery' (as shown the fig below)

[image: Choosing Report Source]

Select **'From an Existing Report'**, and press OK.

Browse the Original Report which you want to duplicate.

Now your Clone or Duplicate Report is ready !

The changes in the reports won't affect each other....

Hope this ll help you. Leave comments if any.

Comment: If at all it is a simple trick, we don't search for this unless the requirement is very time sensitive. Thanks for mentioning this as it did make my effort 70% less.

Answer (score 0):

you can not clone or copy one crystal report into another, instead you can use the same datatable which is assigned to the Invoice.rpt and generate a new crystal report with the datatable.

Comment: I think this type of feature should include in crystal reports which should save a lots time in designing reports. What you think?

Comment: I think this would need to be a feature of Visual Studio, not of Crystal.

Comment: @noa, You are also wright such type of feature is useful in VS

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy and paste and then rename the copied report.